Google GSI Client Libray setting data-login_uri request origin as null resulting in CORS problems
I'm currently implementing Google Sign-In using the Google GSI client library. I've encountered an issue where the origin of the request is set to null during the data-login_uri request. This is problematic as it conflicts with my CORS policy, which doesn't allow "*" for security reasons. As a result, the request is being denied.
Here is the relevant code snippet:
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async></script>
<div id="g_id_onload"
     data-client_id="GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"
     data-context="signin"
     data-ux_mode="popup"
     data-login_uri="LOGIN_URI"
     data-itp_support="true">
</div>

<div class="g_id_signin"
     data-type="standard"
     data-shape="rectangular"
     data-theme="outline"
     data-text="signin_with"
     data-size="large"
     data-logo_alignment="left">
</div>

Is it expected behavior for the request origin to be set as null? If not, how can I resolve this issue?
Thank you for your assistance!

That request is probably not made from the client side, but from Google's servers, I suppose. So no real reason to add an Origin header, from their perspective.

@CBroe That makes a lot of sense! Thank you!

I experienced the same issue, and noted that Google sends the Origin header with the null string value:
Google sending string "null" in the Origin header
So the CORS library in Go is trying to validate that null URL.
I think Google should not send even the header Origin, so the CORS library will not check it and the request could continue without issues.
Our solution has been just to exclude the endpoint that Google is calling from the CORS middleware, so it's not checked.
But I'm still wondering why Google sends the Origin with null string value...
